# How can I use Sessions in Laravel 6 Config File

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

When I try to use session on config/database.php file.

I got errors:

First if I use

```
session('key');
```

Error: **Target class [session] does not exist.**

Secondary:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
Session::get('key');
```

Error: **A facade root has not been set.**

I want to use session for database name.

Comment: are you trying to load db dynamically?

Comment: you can not do this as the session may also be in the database, so you can not use session in the db config file. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have 10+ database for users. Users have database example: database_{userid}, database_{userid} I want to select when user try to login.